# Connect DB automatically in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

In my project I am uploading video through one file. In that I am using DB connections like

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("lmsci3") or die(mysql_error());
```

Here I am connecting manually by giving DB name, username and password. Now I want to connect automatically. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "automatically" ? You always have to give your host, user, password & dbname to connect to a DB. There's no "magic" that will connect to your database without any line of code. Simply put your connection in a connection file and include it or something.

Comment: @Twinfriends I want to do like this `mysql_connect($conversion_db['default']['hostname'], $conversion_db['default']['username'], $conversion_db['default']['password'])or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($conversion_db['default']['database']) or die(mysql_error());`. But when I used this video is not uploading to DB.

Answer (score 2):

To enable `auto connecting`, add the word database to the library array, as indicated in the following file:

`application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['auto connecting'] = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

In database.php

Write the following code, so everytime you don't need to make a connection, you just have to write the code once and can use the models and its functions.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'databasename',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: How does this auto connect?  Just specifying a DB connection does not mean it will automatically be connected?

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic as you can see there is a key named 'default' which is default placed in Codeigniter boot. Thanks